# Scalatest maven plugin1.0: ERROR: -c has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer

Tags: scala, maven

I want test case class to parallel.
but I setting error

[image: 1]

```bash
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ pipeline ---
Exception in thread "ScalaTest-main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -c has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -c to -P.
```

How to test case class parallel on the maven?
as test case :

[image: 2]

Comment: 1.0 is a somewhat old version of the `scalatest-maven-plugin`... have you tried upgrading to the latest version (2.1.0, IIRC)?

Comment: Yes.i already update2.1.0,use afterAll. but afterAll is it possible wait all test case finished after implement？